# REGEX: Match strings that contain a specific word but not strings that merely contain that word

Tags: javascript, regex

For example, I want to match all strings that contain the word 'cat' or 'dog' such as concatenation, doghouse, underdog, catastrophe, or endogamy. But I want to exclude the words dogs or cats from being matched. I tried this task using the following regex.

```
\\w*(cat|dog)(s(?=\w+))*\
```

But this regex doesn't help me select whatever is after the s. Is there some other way to achieve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If the alternated words are of same length, e.g.: [`\b\w*?(?!\b\w{3}s\b)(?:cat|dog)\w*\b`](https://regex101.com/r/GfqR4I/1)

Answer (score 1):

This regex avoids a lookbehind, which is not supported by all browsers.

```js
const regex = /\b(?!cats\b|dogs\b)[a-z]*(?:cat|dog)[a-z]*\b/gi;
const m = 'concatenation, doghouse, underdog, catastrophe, endogamy, dogshore and catstick should match, but not cats and dogs.'.match(regex);
console.log(m);
```

Output:

```
[
  "concatenation",
  "doghouse",
  "underdog",
  "catastrophe",
  "endogamy"
]
```

Explanation of regex:

- `\b` -- word boundary
- `(?!cats\b|dogs\b)` -- negative lookahead for just `cats` or `dogs`
- `[a-z]*` -- optional alpha chars
- `(?:cat|dog)` -- non-capture group for literal `cat` or `dog`
- `[a-z]*` -- optional alpha chars
- `\b` -- word boundary

Comment: This regex works with the following exception. Words such as dogshore or catstick aren't matched with this pattern.

Comment: Indeed, fixed now. When I posted I already fixed that in the explanation of regex, but forgot to carry that back into the regex. Note to self: Don't post at 2am when sleepy :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you also don't want to match `dogsdogs` you might write the pattern as:

```
\b(?!\w*(?:cats\b|dogs\b))\w*(?:cat|dog)\w*
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b` a word boundary
- `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert that to the right is not

  - `\w*(?:cats\b|dogs\b)` Match optional word characters followed by the word cat or dog followed by a word boundary
- `)` Close the lookahead
- `\w*(?:cat|dog)\w*` Match cat or dot between word characters

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FuCUfz/1)

---

If a [lookbehind assertion is supported](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind), and you also want to allow other non whitespace characters, you can use `\S` to match a non whitespace character instead of `\w` that matches a word character.

```
(?<!\S)(?!\S*(?:cats\b|dogs\b))\S*(?:cat|dog)\S*
```

See another [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QTvW5C/1)

Answer (score 1):

I understand your requirements as: match everything that has cat/dog anywhere in word apart from the specific words 'cats' and 'dogs'

```
  \b(?!cats\b|dogs\b)(?=\S*cat\S*|\S*dog\S*)\S*\b
```

*(very)* Rough human translation: Find a point where a word isn't cats or dogs (ending with word boundary) and then find a point where a word has cat or dog (either at start, middle, or end) then match everything till the end of the word from that point

Note: flavour - PCRE2

Comment: a demo of regex above - https://regex101.com/r/mhOCbU/1